# How to store the images and other files uploaded by users of web site/app in the Docker volume safely (with backup possibility)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Although the third-party services like AWS Bucket are the popular solutions for such problems, this question is focused on the solution without third-party services: only Docker and own VPS. *Assume that target web site/application is not intended for the large traffic* (for example, it is the local blog for the narrow audience).

### How it usually done in tutorials and why I don't accept it

Initially, we have the project with the directory which intended to be filled with files which should be statically returned by the server. For the Laravel framework case, it is the `storage/app/public`:

[image]

In some tutorials, the tutors mixes the following 2 types of files in this directory:

1. The files which has been prepared by the developers (for example, stylesheets)
2. The files which has been uploaded by users (mainly images)

I am feeling uncomfortable mixing this two types of files in the **public** directory.
What it the **public** directory will be lost on VPS by some reason?
The static files prepared by developers could be uploaded again because the developers have the instances of these files on own PCs. In contrast to this, without specific measures, the files uploaded by users will be lost *permanently*.

### My distributable

Unlike the PHP + Laravel, in my tech stack the source and output code are *completely* separated.
None of files you see in the picture below has been created manually - all of them been generated by the project building tool, even **package.json**.

[image]

The "ProductionBuild" directory is intended to be deployed to VPS *as is*.
It could be done by **FTP**, but **Rsync** or **Git** with submodule for the output code are advanced options.

Is *must* be completely safe to delete this repository **ProductionBuild** from *both* local PC and VPS because it could be built and uploaded again. *This requirement will not be satisfied anymore if to store the files uploaded by users to `public` directory.*

### My infra

Let me repeat target project is not the SaaS, just the web site or the app with small traffic, thus no need in the heavy artillery like AWS ALB. So, the infra is pretty simple: the server application and database:

[image]

Both server application and database has *own* **Docker container** and **Docker volume**, but there is also the one significant difference:

- The Docker container and Docker volume *for the web application* are *disposable*. Once new version of the application will be deployed, the new Docker container and Docker volume for the web application will be create. Thus, they are *fully independent* from previous ones and of course, does *not* contain the data which loss is critical.
- The Docker container and Docker volume *for the database* are of course reusable. Ever new container for the web application will be created, the data from the database could be reused.

Here are the **docker-compose.yaml** and **Dockerfile** satisfying the above requirements:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  front_server:

    container_name: Example-Production-FrontServer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "FrontServer.Dockerfile"
    ports: [ "80:8080" ]

    depends_on: [ Database ]
    command: sh -c "npm run \"Database migration\" && node FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment production"

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Production-Database
    ports: [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ]

    environment:

      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/Example.jp

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}
```

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/example.com

COPY . /var/www/example.com

RUN npm install --no-package-lock
```

### Goal

Now, it is required to add the new volume and, possibly, container for the storing for the images and other files uploaded by users. Of course they are reusable and loss of them is critical, thus the backup must be provided.

[image]

### Possible solutions

I have not use the Nginx before, but I have heard that it is good for the storing of the static files. If so, maybe it will be the right solution to provide the Nginx container and the volume associated with it.

The possible drawback of this solution are the higher requirements to spec of the VPS.
My VPS has 1GB RAM and CPU 2Core and I am not sure it will be file to add one more container with the web server.

At the same time, is should the solution with new volume but without new container.
The disposable container for the web server will refer to reusable files storage same as to the container and volume for the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store images and other files uploaded by users of your website/app in a Docker volume safely with backup possibility, you can create a dedicated [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for this purpose. That volume will be separate from the volume that contains your server application and database: user-uploaded files must not be lost when you update or dispose of your application container.

You can update your `docker-compose.yml` to include a new [service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/) if you decide to use Nginx for serving static files, or simply add a new volume if you keep serving them via Node.js.
The choice between adding Nginx and just a volume depends on your performance needs and server capabilities. Since your VPS has limited resources, adding Nginx might not be necessary, especially if traffic is low.

A `docker-compose.yml` with a new volume for user-uploaded files, without adding an extra container, would be:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  front_server:
    # existing configuration
    volumes:
      - UserFiles:/path/to/public/uploads # Mount the user files volume to the container

  # existing Database service configuration

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}
  UserFiles: {} # Define the new volume for user-uploaded files
```

For the backup, you can set up a cron job on the host system that periodically backs up the `UserFiles` volume to another location, such as an attached block storage device or even offsite using `rsync`, `scp`, or similar tools.